# Could not find the main class: org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ant.JspCSingle. Program will exit

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, jsp-tags

I have tried again my jsp coding with taglid.  This time round, everything seems to work except when I run it, the following error appears:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/modules/web/project/ant/JspCSingle
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ant.JspCSingle
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Could not find the main class: org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ant.JspCSingle.  Program will exit.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem trying to run a single jsp file in netbeans 6.9
How to solve the prob: Go to librairies manager(tools>libraries) and locate the "Jsp Compilation" library. Use  "Add Jar/Folder" to add the path to your jspCSingle.java file to the library classpath. And that's it.  Note that the "jsp compilation" library is necessary to compile/run single jsp files. So must either have it in your project library or netbeans set of libraries.

Emmanuel